# How to get previous month from 'yyyy-MM' date format in Hive

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql

I want to get previous month from 'yyyy-MM' format value in Hive. I tried with 'add_months' but couldn't able to get.

```
select add_months('2021-06', -1)
```

Eg: I have one string column having value '2021-06', now I want to display output as '2021-05'.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your string to date by concatenating with `'-01'`, `add_months`, use `date_format` to get `yyyy-MM`:

```
select date_format(add_months(concat('2021-06','-01'), -1),'yyyy-MM')
```

Result:

```
2021-05
```

Another method (using `substr` instead of `date_format`):

```
select substr(add_months(concat('2021-06','-01'), -1),1,7) --returns 2021-05
```

Comment: I'm not getting the output when I replaced column name instead of '2021-06' value in hive query i.e year_month=date_format(add_months(concat(year_month,'-01'), -1),'yyyy-MM')

Comment: @ leftjoin, We don't have any other character except 2021-06 in my column. I tried both methods but not getting output. Please find my complete query.
select * from db.test where year_month=date_format(add_months(concat(year_month,'-01'), -1),'yyyy-MM');

select * from db.test where year_month=substr(add_months(concat(year_month,'-01'), -1),1,7);

Comment: @ leftjoin , Thanks for your help !!